# Is GLS really a special case of the GEE?

Tags: regression, least-squares, generalized-estimating-equations, generalized-least-squares

I was told, that the GLS is a special case of the GEE, if the conditional distribution is gaussian and the link is identity.

How is that possible?

- GLS is a two (or more - IWLS) stage procedure. It estimates both the covariance structure in the first place and then uses it to alter the coefficient estimates. In GEE only the SEs are altered (robust).
- GLS is a full likelihood method, while GEE is a semi-parametric method, with quasi likelihood

I understand that:

- the General Linear Model is a special case of the GLM (gaussian, identity link). Both are full likelihood (OLS = MLE in this case)
- the GLS is an extension of the General LM (OLS). Still both are full likelihood methods.
- GEE is an extension of the GLM, so this would be tempting to draw t he line, but GEE is a different method of estimation.

So, finally, how is GLS a special case of the GLM?